# How can I apply styles to td and th?

Tags: html

Please excuse my ignorance on this topic. I am using koolreport in my php application. I am trying to get the font style on text from my database to match the text that I just typed directly into the html view file. [image]

I'd like the font and spacing under 2.1 Company Overview to be the same as Project Basis a few line lower. The "3 word recommendation" of koolreport tech support, :) , is to the styles from copy the good text and "apply them to td, th, not h1->h6". Can anyone translate what that means? I went to inspect for the page and I see

```
.table th, .table td {
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
```

The code that is generating 2.1 is

```
<h2> 2.1 Division Background </h2>
<?php
Table::create(array(
    "dataStore"=>$this->dataStore("campaigns2"),
    "class"=>array(
        "showHeader"=>false,
        "table"=>"table table-hover"

    )
));
?>
```

Can anyone give me a hint of how I "apply it to td and th"?

Comment: Please add the HTML structure. Maybe you simply meant `table th, table td {`

Comment: Sorry, I suspect this isn't going to helpful to you but I'm struggling to see where any `<table>`, `<th>` or `<td>` elements belong on the document displayed. That document ought really be marked up with `<h1>` to `<h6>` and `<p>` and, possibly, `<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dd>`. Nevertheless, I echo @DanielW.'s comment - please add the HTML output to your question.